# Virtualbox, private network and access from host machine

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I want to create a private network between my virtualboxes (say 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4, etc.) but I want them to be accessible from the host machine (local IP 192.168.1.10) and also have access to the internet through the host machine.

What should I do? What kind of network should I setup on virtualbox settings as well as installed CentOS on virtualbox?

Need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add two virtual network adapters to each guest: one configured as NAT for access to the internet and one adapter as Host-Only to be private with your host and other virtual machines. Feel free to use DHCP on both interfaces, or configure a static address as necessary.

Comment: +1 I think each VM needs 2 adapters too.